Algebraic number on the unit circle has norm in the unit circle
Let $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ with modulus 1. For $f$ its minimal polynomial, is it always true that $f(0)$ lies on the unit circle?
I've been trying things and apparently it's not always true that all the Galois conjugates lie on the unit circle, but it seems the claim is still true.
I know the claim would hold for algebraic integers, and also if we assume the Galois group is abelian (so that conjugation commutes with the other embeddings) but this is not enough.

Let $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$. Then $f=X^2-2$ and $f(0)=-2$ is not on the unit circle.

I see. You should write this in your first sentence (I did not look at the title).

Yes it came to my attention, I changed the first sentence

For algebraic integers, this is immediate - the complex conjugate is the inverse so that the number is an integral unit (and therefore has norm $\pm 1$).

@TimSeifert Thank you but I was aware of that, my question is not specifically about algebraic integers (sorry it seems in the comment I said algebraic integer but didn't mean to)

This is correct.
Suppose $\alpha$ is such a number. Then $\alpha^{-1}=\overline{\alpha}$, so that both numbers are conjugate. But then we have
$$N(\alpha)=N(\alpha^{-1})=(N(\alpha))^{-1},$$
which shows that $N(\alpha)=\pm 1$.

Oh I see, thank you!
